# multiple folders created on form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, google-forms

the script running in the background to a google form is returning a new folder and email for every question answered instead of just 1 folder and 1 email.... can anybody help to see where i went wrong!

```
function onSubmit() {
var form = FormApp.openById('123456789abcdefghij');
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
       (i + 1).toString(),
        itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
        itemResponse.getResponse());

var DriveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B2eMBrrkabcdefghij");
 var foldername = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
var folderpath = DriveFolder.createFolder(foldername).getUrl();
var to = itemResponses[1].getResponse();}

 MailApp.sendEmail(
     to,"Change Management Request", "Thank you for Submitting Step 1. Please fill out Step 2 (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2eMBrrkabcdefji) and upload to" +folderpath); 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting the code shows that the parts for creating the folder sending the mail are nested too deep within the `for` loops:

```
function onSubmit() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('123456789abcdefghij');
    var formResponses = form.getResponses();
    for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
        var formResponse = formResponses[i];
        var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
        for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
            var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
            Logger.log(
                'Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
                (i + 1).toString(),
                itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
                itemResponse.getResponse());

            var DriveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B2eMBrrkabcdefghij");
            var foldername = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
            var folderpath = DriveFolder.createFolder(foldername).getUrl();
            var to = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
        }

        MailApp.sendEmail(
            to,
            "Change Management Request",
            "Thank you for Submitting Step 1. Please fill out Step 2 (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2eMBrrkabcdefji) and upload to" +folderpath); 
    }
}
```

Probably you want to move them out, but without knowing which field you want for calculating the folder name, I can only guess:

```
function onSubmit() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('123456789abcdefghij');
    var formResponses = form.getResponses();
    for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
        var formResponse = formResponses[i];
        var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
        for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
            var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
            Logger.log(
                'Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
                (i + 1).toString(),
                itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
                itemResponse.getResponse());
        }
    }

    var DriveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B2eMBrrkabcdefghij");
    var folderAndToResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1].getItemResponses(); 
    var foldername = folderAndToResponse[2].getResponse();
    var folderpath = DriveFolder.createFolder(foldername).getUrl();
    var to = folderAndToResponse[1].getResponse();

    MailApp.sendEmail(
        to,
        "Change Management Request",
        "Thank you for Submitting Step 1. Please fill out Step 2 (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2eMBrrkabcdefji) and upload to" + folderpath); 
}
```